# Mouse stops working on login screen hyper v

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have downloaded the IE8 windows 7 test vmc and have got it loaded onto Hyper-v using the instructions I found here: http://encodo.com/en/blogs.php?entry_id=240

However, when I get to the login screen, I cannot click on any of the icons and I found I can only login using my keyboard to navigate.

Is there anything I need to do to get my mouse to work properly on Hyper V Manager - for example do I have to add more hardware components for the instance of the Virtual Machine?

Also my mouse has the normal cursor instead of the dot cursor that I have read about and my version of Hyper v manager is 6.2 for windows 8

Comment: Where exactly did you get this virtual machine from?  The reason I ask is because you shouldn't have to convert the virtual machine.  If you need a working Hyper-V virtual machine here are a bunch in any possible configuration you need.  http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Comment: I downloaded it from the microsoft site - http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Comment: The virtual machine you downloaded isn't the one you should be downloading they have since replaced it.

Comment: ah right, I'll try the ones in the link above but I fixed my problem anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trawling a lot of similar questions on the internet and a lot of trial and error I have finally figured out how to get the mouse working:

Make sure the VM is not in full screen mode so that you can see the actions (file, action, media, etc) across the top of the window.

Log in to the virtual machine using your keyboard

Once the vm is logged in and has got to the desktop, click on the action menu and select "Insert Integration Services Setup Disk" - this may prompt you to uninstall something (which you can do using the windows and tab keys

Reboot the vm and your mouse should now work

I think my problem was a lot of sites just said you should select the insert setup disk and I was doing it at the login screen so it wasn't doing anything.